# I'm unable to move the cursor in play mode in the Unity VR example scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm using the VR Samples from Unity `https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/51519` with the scene 'Shooter 360' (though I've tried the other scenes).

I'm on a Mac and in XR settings I have both 'Mock HMD - HTC' and 'Oculus SDK' supported.

When I press Play, I'm unable to move the cursor or interact with the GUI at all. Any recommendations?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default it is the *SDK* you use that will rotate the camera at runtime (Cardboard, Oculus, HTC Vive, ...).

You can use a script that will rotate the camera while in edit mode. Here is an example, just assign this script to your camera and press **Left Ctrl** while moving the mouse in the editor window:

```cs
public class EditorCameraController : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public float sensitivityX = 15F;
    public float sensitivityY = 15F;
    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;
    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;
    private float rotationX = 0F;
    private float rotationY = 0F;
    private Quaternion originalRotation;

    void Start()
    {
        originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationX = ClampAngle(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
            rotationY = ClampAngle(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, -Vector3.right);
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
        }
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F)
         angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
         angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```